# How to user instance method in where query inside scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have defined an instance method inside the user model. I want to use that instance method inside the scope but I am not sure how to do that. Please help me find where I am going wrong.

user.rb

```
has_many :users_availables
has_many :availables, through: :users_availables

scope :under_2500_value, -> { joins(:available).where('(value * availables.count / 100) in (?)', 0..2499) }
scope :under_5000_value, -> { joins(:availables).where('(value * availables.count / 100) in (?)', 2500..4999) }

def current_value
  value * available.count / 100
end
```

available is another table that has a relationship with the user table as below.

In the rails console, if I try the below command it returns users who have current_value as 7500  but it should have returned between under 2500.

```
User.under_2500_value
```

Please help me find where I am going wrong.

Result for User.under_2500_value

```
irb(main):033:0> User.under_2500_value.to_sql
=> "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\" INNER JOIN \"users_availables\" ON \"users_availables\".\"user_id\" = \"users\".\"id\" INNER JOIN \"availables\" ON \"availables\".\"id\" = \"users_availables\".\"available_id\" WHERE ((value * availables.count / 100) in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,219,220,221,222,223,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255,256,257,258,259,260,261,262,263,264,265,266,267,268,269,270,271,272,273,274,275,276,277,278,279,280,281,282,283,284,285,286,287,288,289,290,291,292,293,294,295,296,297,298,299,300,301,302,303,304,305,306,307,308,309,310,311,312,313,314,315,316,317,318,319,320,321,322,323,324,325,326,327,328,329,330,331,332,333,334......,2497,2498,2499))"
```

Comment: Can you post the results of `User.under_2500_value.to_sql`

Comment: @Chiperific please check the question, I have posted the result for User.under_2500_value.to_sql

Comment: @spickermann was very kind to you, because *your* scopes don't match: "your both scopes don't match, first one has joins(:available) and the other one has joins(:availables)". He wrote his answer to mirror the code you showed.

Comment: @Chiperific yes for sure he is very kind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`available.count` is a Ruby method that need to be translated into SQL first. For example with a combination of `JOIN`, `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`

Additionally, an expression like `value * availables.count / 100` can lead to results of floating point results, depending on the type of the input.

Lets imaging a value like `25.5` was returned. Then the Ruby expression `(1..100).cover?(25.5)` would be `true`. But when passing a range to SQL it works a bit different and gets translated into an array of integers (just see the end of the generated SQL query in your question):

```
=> "SELECT [...] FROM [...] WHERE ((value * availables.count / 100) in (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,219,220,221,222,223,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255,256,257,258,259,260,261,262,263,264,265,266,267,268,269,270,271,272,273,274,275,276,277,278,279,280,281,282,283,284,285,286,287,288,289,290,291,292,293,294,295,296,297,298,299,300,301,302,303,304,305,306,307,308,309,310,311,312,313,314,315,316,317,318,319,320,321,322,323,324,325,326,327,328,329,330,331,332,333,334......,2497,2498,2499))"
```

And that array obviously doesn't include any floating point numbers like `25.5`.

To solve your question, I would combine above SQL operators with the `BETWEEN` operator instead of `IN`:

```
scope :under_2500_value, -> { 
  joins(:availables).group(:id)
    .having('(value * COUNT(availables) / 100) BETWEEN ? AND ?', 0, 2499) 
}
scope :under_5000_value, -> { 
  joins(:availables).group(:id)
    .having('(value * COUNT(availables) / 100) BETWEEN ? AND ?', 2500, 4999) 
}
```

Comment: your both scopes don't match, first one has joins(:available) and the other one has joins(:availables), first one return ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid and second one returns user records who have current_value over 7500 but it should have returns beween 2500-4999

Comment: @user12763413 I updated my answer to address your comment.

Comment: What about count field in availables tables? You are not using that anymore

Comment: Your question actually is unclear about what `available.count` is. The code in your question only has `has_many :availables` (plural) defined, and `availables.count` would return the number of available. If `available` (singular) is something different and `count` is not the number of availables, but an attribute on a single available then you need to clarify that in your question. It might also be helpful to see your database schema.

Comment: Thankyou sir. Next time i ll be clear with my question